# Send and receive datagram packet

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

sorry for my bad english. I have to send and receive data from phone to radio using bluetooth pan interface on android. This is the code I've implemented to send, I've made it into the function DoInBackground() of AsyncTask:

```
 try
           {

            ds = new DatagramSocket();
            byte buf[] = "Ciao".getBytes();
            DatagramPacket msg = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, InetAddress.getByName(add), p);

            ds.send(msg);

        }
```

and it works perfectly. Now I have to wait 100 seconds the answer of the radio. I decide to implement it with this code:

```
try
       {
           ds.setSoTimeout(10000);

           while(true)
           {
               try
               {
                   ds.receive(dp);
               }
               catch (IOException e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }



       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {

       }
```

but there are three questions:
1. I need to receive the packet at 192.168.11.2 and 1234 port, but when I declared datagramsocket I set it void, because if i put port and address, send code doesn't work;
2. How can I manage the packet I've received by the radio? I don't need to use address and port bytes;
3. Why have I put the timeout before the loop?

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create the datagram socket with just the port number you are after. DatagramSocket(p);

2) You have a DatagramPacket with a bytebuffer of the size of the response and the length of the response i.e:

```
int responseLength = 1024;
byte[] responseData = new byte[responseLength];
DatagramPacket response = new DatagramPacket(responseData, responseLength);
```

After receiving into this datagram packet you need to convert it into same object that it was sent as. Something like this maybe:

```
String s = new String(response.getData());
```

3) The setSoTimeout doesn't cause the message to wait for 100s, it is just saying that after 100s if nothing has been read in by the receive() then it will timeout. This only needs to be set once per connection, setting this multiple times during the loop shouldn't be done.

Hope this helps